# How to add a horizontal line above the footer with fancyhdr?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, rules

How to add a horizontal line above the footer using `fancyhdr`, just like the line present below the header?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Redefine `\footrulewidth`:

```
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% default is 0pt
```

To learn more about `fancyhdr`, you could either look into [its documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fancyhdr) or at the [respective chapter in the Wikibook LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Customising_with_fancyhdr).

Comment: I added a couple of resources from a similar answer I was going to give on another question, hope that's okay.

Comment: This works, but not on the first page when using the `article` document class. How to also add a line above the page number "1"?